# Making a function interactive in shiny

Tags: shiny

A txt.file `data` contaning a matrix of integers with 5 integers for each column and 1000 rows.

So if we press

```
data
```

we get this output

```
96520
69850
...
36884
```

We can get a random row by this

```
getnumbers <- sample(data,1, replace=FALSE)
```

By getting a random row in `data` the task is to enter the next row (by press a,b,c,d,e) and check if it's correct. So if we have the kth entry in `data` we want to get the k+1 entry in `data` by pressing the digits and see if it's correct.

```
check <- function(a,b,c,d,e){
if( identical( data[k+1] , c(a,b,c,d,e)) == TRUE ) {
return("Correct") }
else{return("Not correct")}
```

How can I implement this R code in Shiny so I can make it interactive using ubuntu ?

Comment: So you want to select a row by random from your dataset, get a user input and see if it matches the next row in the dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I understood your question correctly but here's how you could do it:

```
library(shiny)
data <- matrix(round(runif(5*3)),ncol=3)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(6, h4("Randomly Selected Row [k]")),
    column(6, h4("Nex Row [k+1]"))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(6, textOutput("selRow")),
    column(6, textOutput("nxtRow"))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(8, textInput("guessStr","Gues row: ")),
    column(4, actionButton("guess","guess"))
  ),
  textOutput("guessRes")
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  # Make the current rownumber a reactive
  r.num <<- 0
  makeReactiveBinding('r.num')

  # If rownumber changes update UI
  observe({
    if(is.null(r.num)) return(NULL)
    output$selRow <- renderPrint({data[r.num,]})
    output$nxtRow <- renderPrint({data[r.num+1,]})
  })

  # Get a row number by random, can't select last row
  randomRow <- function(){
    r.num <<- sample(1:nrow(data)-1, 1)
  }

  # If user presses guess button
  observeEvent(input$guess, {
    # I convert to numerical but this can be modified to work with characters to
    input.str <- as.numeric(strsplit(input$guessStr,',')[[1]])

    msg <- sprintf("You guessed that the next row is: %s",input$guessStr)
    if( identical(data[r.num+1,], input.str)){
      msg <- paste(msg," , this was correct!")
    }
    else{
      msg <- paste(msg," , this was wrong")
    }
    output$guessRes <- renderPrint({msg})
  })

  # Initiate the guessing by randmozing a row
  randomRow()
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```